# set default print size. wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

Im trying to print out the content inside a Grid in wpf-window.
the problem is that i have to choose the size of the paper each time i want to print. the size is 62mm*45mm.

i have tried this code to set it but i ddnt work.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Alashi", 15, 4);//("PaperA4", 840, 1180);
            pd.Print();
```

or this, without size settings

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                printDialog.PrintVisual(MyGrid1, "My First Print Job");
            }
```